# How to loop a function for a progress bar on a slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slideshow that changes images with an interval of `5000`.

The function to show the progress bar between one image and the other is as follows:

```
function timebar(){
    $('#timebar').stop().css({width:0});
    $('#timebar').animate({width:'100%'},5000);
}
```

I call this after the slideshow has loaded so that they process at the same time.

I want this function to loop so that the timebar is reset for each slide:

```
function timebar(){
    $('#timebar').stop().css({width:0});
    $('#timebar').animate({width:'100%'},5000);
    setTimeout(timebar(),5000);
}
```

However, when this is done, I get the error `Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

How can I have this function repeat every `5000`ms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the function reference to `setTimeout`, currently you are recursively calling `timebar()` function and `setTimeout` has no use at all.

You need to use

```
setTimeout(timebar,5000);
```

instead of

```
setTimeout(timebar(),5000);
```

Comment: @BenPearlKahan, you are recursively calling `timebar()` function

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a function reference to `setTimeout`, in your case you are making infinte recursive calls by invoking the function `timebar()`.

Since you have an infinite recursive call the call stack size will be exceeded.

```
function timebar(){
    $('#timebar').stop().css({width:0});
    $('#timebar').animate({width:'100%'},5000);
    setTimeout(timebar,5000);
}
```